# SQL JOIN on column with two others

Tags: sql, join

I have the following tables:

Table1:

| id | name | model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | ar |
| 1 | 1 | st |

Table2:

| id | name | model2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | th |
| 1 | 1 | st |

Table_keys:

| model | model number |
| --- | --- |
| ar | 127 |
| st | 234 |
| th | 338 |

And trying to create one table as following:

Table_result:

| id | name | model | model2 | model number_1 | model number_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | ar | th | 127 | 338 |

How can I join the two tables with the keys table twice? I used left outer join but then "model number 1" can be matched with either model1 or model2, I need to use "model number" again, in a new column but for model2

Comment: What is your current SQL request ? Also, can you add tag for your db ? (mysql, sql-server ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join on `table_keys` twice, with two different aliases:

```
SELECT    t1.id, t1.name, t1.model, t2.model2,
          tk1.model_number AS model_number_1,
          tk2.model_number AS model_number_2
FROM      table1 t1
JOIN      table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name
LEFT JOIN table_keys tk1 ON t1.model = tk1.model
LEFT JOIN table_keys tk2 ON t2.model2 = tk2.model
```

Comment: Thanks that works, just one little thing, I want to see a row even if one (or both) of the model numbers do not exist. Then there will be no values in model_number1 or 2

Comment: @Oliver using a `left join` instead of an inner ("regular") join should do the trick. See my edited answer.